# How to deal with exceptions in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, exception, try-except

When working with selenium, you often work (almost always) with elements on the page, while selenium itself does not report errors well, so it’s logical to use "try catch", but it looks like this:

```py
for link in link_list:
    web_driver.get(link)
    
    try:
        web_driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, XPath.BUTTON_EXPAND_LOGIN_BY_PASSWORD.value
            ).click()
    except NoSuchElementException as error:
        print('Element not found button "Login by password"')
        raise NoSuchElementException(error)

    try:
        web_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, XPath.INPUT_LOGIN.value).send_keys(LOGIN)
    except NoSuchElementException as error:
        print('Login field not found.')
        raise NoSuchElementException(error)

    try:
        web_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, XPath.INPUT_PASSWORD.value).send_keys(
            PASSWORD
            )
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('Password field not found.')
        raise NoSuchElementException(error)
```

Is it possible to do the same thing more elegant or something, otherwise it's somehow ugly?

Comment: Instead of having 3 try blocks, you can have all the code in 1 try block because if the test fails at a particular step you would generally want to debug that step before continuing with the next ones as they are most likely to fail

Comment: You are right, not a good example, the problem is rather when working with lists of links, without exceptions it is difficult to understand where the error appeared (when working with selenium).